# PHP MySQL joining two tables with conditional joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

So, I have a database that I am creating. It stores information about families and each family member. It then uses those records to associate invoices to either a family or family member.

My dilemma is that I need to list all of these invoices to a page under the families record i.e. create a list of invoices associated to either the family itself or an individual family member.

**Table Structure**

invoices

```
id | date_entered | invoice_date | invoice_number | invoice_amount | client_type | unique_id | supplier_type | supplier_id | category_id | childcare_hours
---+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------
1  | 1411098397   | 1411048800   | 123            | 0.01           | 0           | 137       | 0             | 139         | 5           | NULL
```

families

```
id |  ufi     |   last_name     | address_1   | address_2 | city_id | phone | mobile | email | f_d_worker_1 | f_d_worker_2 | status_id | trans_date | entry_date | exit_date | eligible_date | active_date | lga_loc_id | facs_loc_id | ind_status_id | referral_id | active_status | comm_org_id | notes
---+----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------
1  | 1-XEWUDZ | Forsyth - Ennis | Skinner St. | NULL      | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  | 13           | NULL         | 1         | NULL       | 1341324000 | NULL      | 1341842400    | 1342620000  | 7          | 1           | 3             | NULL        | 1             | 1           | NULL
```

clients (family members)

```
id |   upi    | last_name | first_name | birthdate  | sex | phone | mobile | email | indig_status_id | referral_id | relationship_id | preschool_id | family_id | notes
---+----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----+-------+--------+-------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+------
 1 | 1-XFCBBP | Ennis     | Jason      | 20/09/1996 | 1   | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  | 3               | NULL        | NULL            | NULL         | 1         | NULL
```

My current SQL looks like:

```
SELECT `invoices`.`id`, `invoices`.`date_entered`, `invoices`.`invoice_date`, `invoices`.`invoice_number`, `invoices`.`invoice_amount`, `invoices`.`client_type`, `invoices`.`unique_id`, `unique1`.`ufi`, `unique2`.`upi`, `unique1`.`last_name`, `invoices`.`supplier_type`, `invoices`.`supplier_id`, `suppliers`.`name`,  `invoices`.`category_id`, `cat1`.`name`, `cat2`.`name`, `invoices`.`childcare_hours` 
FROM `invoices` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `suppliers` ON `suppliers`.`id` = `invoices`.`supplier_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` cat1 ON `cat1`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `preschool_types` cat2 ON `cat2`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `families` unique1 ON `unique1`.`id` = `invoices`.`unique_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients` unique2 ON `unique2`.`id` = `invoices`.`unique_id` 
WHERE (`invoices`.`unique_id` = ? AND `unique1`.`ufi` = ?) LIMIT 0, 10
```

But what I need a query that checks the `client_type` column and if it equals 1 it needs to look in the `clients` table BUT it needs to look for members of the same family, identified by the id row in the `families` table

## SOLUTION

Ok, so after much, much (much) screwing around and a little research. It appears that @cupid was correct (Although very brief in his answer).

And I will explain the solution better (in hope that this will help someone later).

The [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) option in MySQL (and most likely other SQL) allows you to combine the result sets of two (or more) SELECT queries, into one result set. This is extremely helpful if you have similar data, in separate tables that you may want to select easily and process as one request. Also helpful (in my case) for pagination, by allowing you to utilise SQL's LIMIT option.

One thing to take into consideration is that, the UNION syntax uses the columns from the first SELECT statement as the column names for all following queries, also you need to make sure that you have the same amount of columns selected in all queries for this to work.

```
(
    SELECT 
        `invoices`.`id`, 
        `invoices`.`date_entered`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_date`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_number`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_amount`, 
        `invoices`.`client_type`, 
        `invoices`.`unique_id`, 
        `clients`.`upi`, 
        `clients`.`last_name`, 
        `clients`.`family_id`,
        `invoices`.`supplier_type`, 
        `invoices`.`supplier_id`, 
        `suppliers`.`name`, 
        `invoices`.`category_id`, 
        `cat1`.`name`, 
        `cat2`.`name`, 
        `invoices`.`childcare_hours` 
    FROM
    (
        `invoices` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `suppliers` ON `suppliers`.`id` = `invoices`.`supplier_id`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` cat1 ON `cat1`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `preschool_types` cat2 ON `cat2`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.`id` = `invoices`.`unique_id`)
        WHERE 
            `clients`.`family_id` = 47 AND `invoices`.`client_type` = 1
    )
UNION
( 
    SELECT 
        `invoices`.`id`,
        `invoices`.`date_entered`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_date`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_number`, 
        `invoices`.`invoice_amount`, 
        `invoices`.`client_type`, 
        `invoices`.`unique_id`, 
        `families`.`ufi`, 
        `families`.`last_name`,
        `families`.`id`,
        `invoices`.`supplier_type`, 
        `invoices`.`supplier_id`, 
        `suppliers`.`name`, 
        `invoices`.`category_id`, 
        `cat1`.`name`, 
        `cat2`.`name`, 
        `invoices`.`childcare_hours` 
    FROM `invoices`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `suppliers` ON `suppliers`.`id` = `invoices`.`supplier_id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` cat1 ON `cat1`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `preschool_types` cat2 ON `cat2`.`id` = `invoices`.`category_id`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `families` ON `families`.`id` = `invoices`.`unique_id`
    WHERE 
        `invoices`.`unique_id` = 47 AND `invoices`.`client_type` = 0
)
```

Comment: I would go with more simpler queries that each does one thing, then join them outside SQL.

Comment: @VladGURDIGA I would prefer to use it as one query as I need to count the rows for pagination function (which also uses the SQL LIMIT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using UNION?

Comment: Would you have an example for me?

Comment: SELECT data WHERE client_type = 0 UNION SELECT data JOIN family data here WHERE client_type = 1 http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct although it was very brief. When answering a question, please try and include an example or some kind of reference. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. And I'm happy that I could help you in some way. Sorry, for short answer. I actually just started answering in the site. Hopefully I'll get used to the customs soon.